# How to each item in list with all values of another list in Python

Tags: python

Given two lists like:

```
snippets1 = ["aka", "btb", "wktl"]
snippets2 = ["tltd", "rth", "pef"]
```

How can I make a third list from the other two, so that index[0] from list 1 has all of the indexes from list 2 added to it in turn (each being a separate entry in the new list), and then the same for index[1] from list1, and so on? That is, the result should be

```
resultlist = ["akatltd", "akarth", "akapef", "btbtltd", "btbrth", "btbpef", "wktltltd", "wktlrth", "wktlpef"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this

```
resultlist=[]
for i in snipppets1:
 for j in snippets2:
  resultlist.append(i+j)
print resultlist
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was trying to get to initially but I kept messing it up

Answer (score 11):

```
import itertools

snippets1 = ["aka", "btb", "wktl"]
snippets2 = ["tltd", "rth", "pef"]

resultlist = [''.join(pair) for pair in itertools.product(snippets1, snippets2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

And for completeness sake, I suppose I should point out the one liner not using `itertools` (but the itertools approach with `product` should be preferred):

```
[i+j for i in snippets1 for j in snippets2]
# ['akatltd', 'akarth', 'akapef', 'btbtltd', 'btbrth', 'btbpef', 'wktltltd', 'wktlrth', 'wktlpef']
```